# Is it possible to get JSmooth to show a splash screen (-splash:image.png option)

Tags: java, splash-screen

I wrap by application up as an exe using Jsmooth but I can see no way to take advantage of Java 6 splashscreen option.

Ive tried adding splash=splash.png to the java properties section without success, but I guess that is wrong as its not a property, Ive also tried adding
 SplashScreen-Image: splash.png to the manifest of the main jar, neither worked.

Just want to know if its possible or not

Comment: @user294896: As an alternative, Launch4j has the support for splash screen image (under the Splash tab).

Comment: thx, perhaps I should convert to Launch4j I didnt think this software was updated anymore but just looked at the changelog and then has recently been an update after three years of inactivity !

Comment: dangit, there's a request to support it in the project tracker, but no action taken. Gah!

Answer (score 0):

Using the manifest file with the `SplashScreen-Image: splash.png`, should work.  Try the example further down the page on the tutorial I have linked below.  Also, make sure you have a new line after each item in the manifest.

**How to Use a JAR File to Display Splash Screen**

If your application is packaged in a JAR file, you can use the SplashScreen-Image option in a manifest file to show a splash screen. Place the image in the JAR file and specify the path in the option as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: <class name>
SplashScreen-Image: <image name>
```

Taken from: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html

Comment: No it doesnt for me, if I run the jar directly using java -jar it does work, but doesnt work when ran in JSmooth